# What is the type of a companion object in Scala?

Tags: scala

For example, I have:

```
class AClass {

}
object AClass{

}
```

.....

```
println(AClass.getClass.toString)
println((new AClass).getClass.toString)
println(AClass.toString)
println((new AClass).toString)
```

When I tried to print out the types of the class and the companion object,I got:

```
class tmp.AClass$
class tmp.AClass
tmp.AClass$@44a664f2
tmp.AClass@7f9fcf7f
```

I think the type of an instance of the class AClass is AClass.

What is the type of the companion object AClass? What is the dollar symbol's meaning in `AClass$`?

What is the type of the class AClass? Can I use the class AClass directly without make an instance of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dollar sign is a valid part of a class name on the JVM.  You will see it commonly used in generated classes.  So `AClass$` is just a normal class name with nothing special about it.

Of course that's only it's run-time type that it gets compiled to.  Within scala code, the type of the companion to `AClass` is `AClass.type`

Comment: By " run-time type" do you mean in the finally generated Java bytecodes? I used javap and found there is a class AClass$. 
What is the relation between AClass.type and AClass?

Comment: `AClass.type` is the type of the only instance of `AClass$` fron within the Scala type system. Since Scala compiles down to bytecode, and the JVM doesn't really support the singleton concept, Scala compiles your companions to their own class and the Scala compiler ensures it only gets instantiated once. So you end up having `AClass.type` as the type of your companion in your code, and `AClass$` as its *runtime* type (which doesn't really matter)